# how to use multi select in django forms

Tags: python, django, forms

I just want to use multiselect dropdown using django forms

I have tried but simple multichecklist is comming

class Hotel(models.Model):

```
# COUNTRY =(
#     ('INDIA','INDIA'),
#     ('sri','sri'),
#     ('pak','pak')
# )

hotel_Main_Img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
# geo = MultiSelectField(choices = COUNTRY,null =True,blank=True)

geo = models.ForeignKey(Geo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
free_tag = models.ForeignKey(FreeTag,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
default = models.ForeignKey(Default,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
```

for forms.py
class HotelForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
geo = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Hotel.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

class Meta:
    model = Hotel
    fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

1-widget=FilteredSelectMultiple
or 
2- widget=Select2MultipleWidget (for this you have to install django_select2)

You can follow  `https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/get_started.html`